# asp:ListItem item to be auto checked in a CheckBoxList

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist, listitem

How to only auto check option 3 if the if statement below is true?
I have the following in my .aspx:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CB_Test" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Text="Opt 1" Value="1" />
<asp:ListItem Text="Opt 2" Value="2" />
<asp:ListItem Text="Opt 3" Value="3" />
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

In the .aspx.cs page,

```
if(variable = "3")
CB_Test.Checked = true;
```

The above is not working for me.

Comment: in which event are you doing this>?

Comment: in item databound event you should be able to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you wanna check particular item depends on the value instead of the `CheckBoxList` itself.

Therefore, what you want should be something like

```
foreach (ListItem item in CB_Test.Items)
{
    if (item.Value == "3")
        item.Selected = true;
}
```